# Conditioning Gaussian process regression

Tags: gaussian, normal-distribution

I was wondering how I could condition a Gaussian process (e.g., by adjusting a  covariance function?) to produce only those trajectories that meet some pre-set constraints. As an example, the following code written in R produces smooth curves (Figure 1) and I'd like to make curves start from the origin, i.e, f(0)=0. Further, would it be possible to force additional characteristics, e.g., make all curves concave down and just one inflection point, etc.

```
require(MASS) ## mvrnorm function is needed 
## to generate covariance matrix using a squared exponential function
calc.sigma <- function( X1, X2, sigma_sq, phi_sq, tau_sq ) {
    Sigma <- matrix( rep( 0, length(X1)*length(X2) ), nrow=length(X1) )
    for( i in 1:nrow(Sigma) ) {
        for( j in 1:ncol(Sigma) ) {
            Sigma[i,j] <- sigma_sq*exp(-phi_sq*(X1[i] - X2[j])^2) + ifelse(i==j, tau_sq, 0.0);
        }
    }
    return(Sigma)
}

x <- seq(0,1,len=100) # input value
## parameters for covariance function 
sigma_sq <- 1 
phi_sq <- 10
tau_sq <- 1e-6

## parameters for mean function
a <- 1
b <- 5
mu <- a*( 1-exp(-b*x) ) # mean
# plot(mu)

sigma <- calc.sigma( x, x , sigma_sq, phi_sq, tau_sq )

N <- 10 # number of samples
samples <- matrix( rep( 0, length(x)*N ), ncol=N )
for ( i in 1:N ) {
    samples[,i] <- mvrnorm( 1, mu, sigma )
}

plot( x, samples[,1], type="l", xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(-5,5) )
for( i in 2:ncol(samples) ){
    lines( x, samples[,i] ) 
}
```

[Figure 1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T69du.png)

Answer (score 1):

The first property that you are requesting is very easy to achieve:

- *the samplepaths of your GP will satisfy the property **f(0)=0 almost surely** if, and only if, the mean function and the variance function vanish at x=0.*
- Note that this is only possible for a **non-stationary** GP (or for the trivial GP with null mean and variance functions, of course).
- A typical example of this the standard Brownian motion over [0; +\infty), which has a zero mean function and covariance function k(x,y) = min(x,y).
- Starting from a generic covariance function k0, you can obtain this property using the conditioning formula: k(x,y) = k0(x,y) - k0(x,0) k0(0,y) / k0(0,0).

All the above can be generalized to any property which is an equality constraint on some values of the function, or linear combination of such.

Conditioning with respect to affine constraints is possible but harder:

- Monotonicity of the samplepaths is equivalent to an infinite number of positivity constraints on the derivative (one at each point).
- Concavity of the samplepaths is equivalent to an infinite number of positivity constraints on the second derivative.
- Approximate versions of these properties can be enforced by conditioning a GP on a finite number of such constraints.  The resulting process, however, is not a GP anymore.  See, e.g., [1] for more details.
- I don't know if there are any ready-to-use packages out there that propose this.

[1] S. Da Veiga & A. Marrel (2012), *Gaussian process modeling with inequality constraints*, Annales de la faculté des sciences de Toulouse Mathématiques, 21(3), 529-555.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me an opaque understanding of Gaussian processes. 
While having many trajectories from experiments, one can check if they are results of a Gaussian process, one can model them as Gaussian process and find an average or error in estimating the average.
But the other way round it is not possible: even if one has an exact model of a Gaussian process, the trajectories in every experiment will be different - as what happen in the process undergoes the normal distribution... 
Therefore **no, you can not obtain predictable behavior** (a given trajectory, not even a family of trajectories sharing some characteristics) from probabilistic process, even if you can shape probabilistic features of the process.

Comment: Thanks for your note.  Sure, the process is probabilistic. No question about it. However I think the parameters for the mean and the covariance functions do allow some control over the process.  As an extreme example, I thought that setting the covariance to zero in the first row and column produce only zeros (i.e., f(0)=0 in my original posting).  However, the trajectory is not smooth any more near zero. I was thinking that adjusting covariance function might resolve this issue and asking for help.